# Does anyone have a debugger that works in version 10.+?

Tags: bugs, debugging

**Bug introduced in 10.0.2 and fixed in 10.2.0**

---

The debugger from mma version 10.0 to 10.1.0 is broken for me. I have Windows 8.1 64-bit. When I step through a function using the debugger then the function is run several times. This problem didn't happen in previous mma versions.
For example:

```
f[]:=Module[{},
x=1;
i++;
x=2;
];
```

If I then run

```
i=0;
f[];
i
```

I get 1.

But if I turn on the debugger, and put a breakpoint at line x=1, and then  continue after the debugger stops, my result is 2.
And if I step through the function, my result is 5.
This means the function f is run 5 times, just by me stepping through the function once using the debugger!

Does anyone else have this problem? Is it just Windows, or windows 64 bit versions of mma? Is there a known way to avoid this problem?

Comment: I get a similar result, good question.

Comment: This used to work properly in v9.01. I would be in favor of tagging this with the [tag:bugs] tag, or tagging at least one other question about the debugger with [tag:bugs].