# stop notebook evaluation when Assert fails

Tags: evaluation, notebooks, coding-style, assertion

I would like a notebook evaluation to entirely stop  when an `Assert` fails, without quitting the kernel.  Is this possible (e.g., by setting `$AssertFunction` to ... something)?

**Edit:**

For example, if I create a notebook containing a cell with the following lines, I would like the value of `test` to still be `0`, and for no subsequent cells to be exectuted.

```
test = 0;
Assert[False];
test = 1;
```

**EDIT:**

Note that setting `$AssertFunction=Abort[]&` does not work, because it only aborts the current computation, but afterwards evaluation continues to proceed through the notebook.

A related question: why must we execute `On[Assert]` before we can set `$AssertFunction`?  Naturally I understand why we must turn assertions on and off; that is not my question.  My question is why `On[Assert]` apparently **resets** `$AssertFunction`:

```
On[Assert] 
$AssertFunction = Abort[] &;
Assert[False]  (* aborts *)
Off[Assert]
On[Assert]
Assert[False]  (* does not abort *)
```

Comment: I see, that's because `Abort[]` aborts the current evaluation.  You are evaluating a whole notebook at once. That's different: the front end will queue up all inputs and send them *one by one* to the kernel.  `Abort[]` only aborts one of these, as it cannot affect the front end state.  `Abort[]` is only for the kernel.  I thought `$AssertFunction = FrontEndTokenExecute["EvaluatorAbort"] &` would work but it doesn't.  I suggest editing the question and spelling out what I said above to attract more attention (i.e. spelling out that `Abort` doesn't work).

Comment: The reason why we need `On[Assert]` is so that we can easily turn on and off the assertions. It's like `-DNDEBUG` when compiling C code.

Comment: @Szabolcs I'd say the fact that "EvaluatorAbort" token is not working is a bug. It doesn't even when I select the cell with `SelectionMove`.

Comment: @Kuba aborting evaluation in the debugger also doesn't work properly, that might be related ([one example](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/81000/4330), feel free to add the bugs tag there).

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I don't really know, could you ask support what one should expect after evaluating Abort[] - newline - Print[1] or after Pause[5] - newline - Print[5] where during pause menu item AbortEvaluation is used? My mails to  WRI are still being lost.

Comment: @Kuba okido, I put that in a brand new todo list :P (temporary message)

Answer (score 13):

```
On[Assert]
$AssertFunction := (
    (*1*)
   SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, Notebook, AutoScroll -> False];
   FrontEndExecute @ FrontEndToken @ "RemoveFromEvaluationQueue";
   SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], After, Cell, AutoScroll -> False];
    (*2*)
   RunScheduledTask[$Pre =., {1}];
       $Pre = Abort[] &; Abort[];
);
```

1. First procedure removes all queued cells from the evaluation queue. And puts a selection after a current evaluating cell.
2. Since no `Token` or `Abort` works, let's improvise to abort pending evaluation in current evaluation cell. Each *line*(not really a line) is a separate `CompoundExpression` which needs to be aborted separately so we can `$Pre` the `Abort[]` operation. But it would be nice to get rid of that later, that's where `ScheduledTask` comes in. 1 second is arbitrary but I think enough to abort everything and not to interrupt user actions in future.

[image]

Everything from main cell after `Assert` is aborted and the cell with `4` is skipped from evaluation even though it was selected too.

Comment: Interesting.  Needless to say, I supposed something simpler was possible.  Can you also address my secondary question?  That is, why must the definition of `$AssertFunction` come after `On[Assert]`?  That is, I find it odd that `On[Assert]` overrides the current definition of `$AssertFunction`; is there a good reason for this?

Comment: @Alan I don't know at the moment :/

Answer (score 7):

As of Version 11.2 RunScheduledTask has been superseded by SessionSubmit. @Kuba 's cool function stopped working on 11.2 but does work when RunScheduledTask is replaced.

Comment: `Version 11.2`  I just checked portal site and do not see `11.2` released? is this a pre-release you are using?

Comment: @Nasser - yes, it is a pre-release.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to inspect the stack when an assertion fails. Will `Dialog` do what you want? As in

```
$AssertFunction:=Dialog[]
```

As [already mentioned](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98882/stop-notebook-evaluation-when-assert-fails#comment268854_98882) however, cells queued for evaluation, and even subsequent lines in the current cell, will still execute when you `Return` or `ExitDialog`. You can `ExitDialog[Unevaluated[Abort[]]]` to abort a statement, but

```
test=0;
Assert[False];
test=1;
```

is three statements.

Answer (score 0):

This is such a fantastic post! One of my notebooks opens a database that is in the current directory but if I have opened a notebook in a different directory, then it fails to find the database and all subsequent evaluations are wrong. Therefore I wanted to test the directory and `Abort` the evaluation of all pending cells if it is wrong. But because sometimes I am on my laptop and sometimes on my desktop, only the \Documents part of the path is constant. Using this answer updated to 12.2 produces the following, which works like a charm:

```
fpath=(NotebookBrowseDirectory/.Options[$FrontEnd])<>"\\";(*save in notebook path*)
(*stop evaluation if the path does not end in \Documents\*)
If[StringTake[fpath,-11]!="\\Documents\\",
(*Remove cells from evaluation queue*)(
SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[],All,Notebook,AutoScroll -> False];
FrontEndExecute@FrontEndToken@"RemoveFromEvaluationQueue";
SelectionMove[EvaluationCell[], After, Cell, AutoScroll -> False];
(*set $Pre to abort current cell but before that schedule a task to un-define $Pre*)
SessionSubmit[ScheduledTask[$Pre =., {Quantity[3, "Seconds"]}]];
MessageDialog["Wrong working directory! Open and close a file in /Documents and rerun."];
$Pre=Abort[]&;Abort[];)];
```

Many thanks @Kuba. It could only be made better by avoiding or redirecting the production of an output cell with `$Aborted` for each subsequent line in the evaluation cell.