# Difference between Initialization Cell and Group

Tags: evaluation, notebooks, options, cells, function-comparison

Is there a difference between setting a `Cell` or a `Group` of cells to be an `Initialization Cell` versus an `Initialization Group` versus doing both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### `InitializationGroup` vs group of `InitializationCells`

If you create a new cell in an `InitializationGroup` it will automatically become an `InitializationCell`.

For the group of `InitializationCells` you will get a default one, which you can turn into another `InitializationCell` or not.

---

#### A set of `InitializationCells` vs one `InitializationCell`.

I can't find any difference in terms of initialization behavior. I'd say it's a matter of taste, for more than one cell you can use some styles to comment/group them for readability.

There are also some subtle differences when it comes to aborting ([stop notebook evaluation when Assert fails](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98882/5478) etc. But nothing strictly related to initialization.