# Abort all evaluations via command

Tags: evaluation, kernel

Is there a command to abort all evaluations in a Mathematica Kernel? Basically I want something like:

```
 somecode;
 AbortAll[];
 morecode;
```

Where the `AbortAll[]` command stops all running and queued evaluations. I cannot find a command for this, only drop-down menu options or pressing `alt+.`

Comment: Why not Abort[]?

Comment: A duplicate old Q on StackOverflow: "[How to abort evaluation of a sequence of inputs?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5625648/590388)"

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov or maybe: [98882](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98882/5478)

Comment: This question is very old, but there is apparently still no built-in command to do this. A workaround is to use `Interrupt` and select "Abort Command Being Evaluated" in the dialog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Mathematica 11.0.1 on Windows 10 or Linux (openSuse) this does work:

```
 abortAll[] := FrontEndTokenExecute["EvaluatorAbort"];
        Do[Print[i]; If[i > 2, abortAll[]]; Pause[.2]; , {i, 10}]

        Print["*"]; abortAll[]; Print["**"];
```

works on Linux.

On Windows it depends on the setting of `CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, PrintAction]`:
For the default `CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, PrintAction] = "PrintToNotebook";` the second print cell with "**" shows up. However, for `CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, PrintAction] = "PrintToConsole";` (as I have it normally, even though I do not understand why it is called "PrintToConsole", since it prints to a Messages window) there is only one Print executed.

[image]

On Linux it just works consistently.

On macOS 10.12 using Mathematica 11.0.1 always both Print's are evaluated.

If anybody cares to use this on the cloud, then:

```
If[$Notebooks&&!$CloudEvaluation,CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, PrintAction] = "PrintToConsole"]; 
abortAll[] := If[$Notebooks&&!$CloudEvaluation, FrontEndTokenExecute["EvaluatorAbort"],Abort[]]; 
Print["*"]; abortAll[]; Print["**"];
```

which leaves me puzzled why `$Notebooks` is `True` when `$CloudEvaluation` is `True`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me: `Print["*"];abortAll[];Print["**"];` still prints both "*" and " ** " (when on separate lines, of course). Moreover, my understanding is that it is impossible to do when lines are entered one by one in a cell and not wrapped in some head (like `head[a;b;c]`), since every such "top level" line is sent to the kernel by FE as a separate evaluation.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin That it does not work for you is a bug in the macOS version. On Windows it works in 11.0.1.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know this was possible. Can't check right now on Windows, but thanks for the info.

Comment: Note however that placing things in `Do` is different from what was originally posted and from what I was considering. Now that there is a wrapper around the code, it is all sent to the kernel as a single evaluation, so I am not so surprised that it works in this case. So, does the original code in the question (or my version) also abort with your construct?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin The FrontEnd is still an interesting piece of sofware. Full of surprises.

Comment: It also really matters whether the statements are in one line, or in separate lines, *if* they are "top-level" in the cell (that is, not wrapped in something). FrontEnd sends separate "top-level" lines as separate evaluations to the kernel, and this is why `Abort` in one does not affect the others. If all statements are in one line, however, then that line is sent to the kernel as a single evaluation, and then `Abort` in the middle statement will indeed affect those after it in that line.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin yep it is tricky:  [98882](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98882/5478). I don't know why there are tools missing to handle basic activities in FE.

Comment: @Kuba Somehow I forgot about that one, even though there is my vote there for both the question and your answer. Thanks for reminding about it.