# any way to stop all the following evaluations?

Tags: evaluation, warning-messages, error-trapping, abort

I often slect the whole notebook to evaluate. Sometimes some functions may return wrong parameters, which may happen, for example, I may have forgotten to specify values to some variables in the function, or due to some internal errors such as reading a file failed. When this happens, the subsquent evaluations could take extremely long time, which can't be exited using Alt+/, and I have to Quit the kernal or shut down the softward completely when it is freezing.

Hence, I'd like to stop all the subsquent evaluations once I found an error, like I got an $Failed flag after reading a file. The Abort[] can only skip one execution. I wonder if there is any command to stop all the subsquent evaluations, so that I can use the command to stop the subsquent evaluations when I detect an error flag?

I already seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127850/abort-all-evaluations-via-command), but doesn't work for me on windows 10. The two prints * and ** are both printed in the notebook.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you also see [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99582/4999) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/152515/4999)?

Comment: @MichaelE2, thanks for the comments, the approach by Kuba does work, though it's more complex than I have expected. I wonder if I have to include the definition of the assertfunction in any nb file that need to use it? Or can I embedd it in the functions  (within user-defined packages) which needs to use the Assert[]? Alternatively, is there anyway to set it as defaults, so that it takes effect in any notebook, even if I restart the kernel?  If so, how can I reset it, and see the list of options that I overwrite? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You might find use in this definition of [`$Post`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Post.html):

```
$Post = Function[, 
       Unevaluated[#] /. $Failed :> 
     RuleCondition@FrontEndTokenExecute["EvaluatorAbort"], HoldAllComplete];
```

With this defined any *printed* output that contains [`$Failed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Failed.html) should trigger an abort of all subsequent cells.

Reference:

- [Pure function with attributes of arbitrary number of arguments: Is it possible?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29168/121)
- [Replacement inside held expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29317/121#29319)