# Remove cell from evaluation queue without aborting evaluation?

Tags: front-end, evaluation, scheduling

Let's say that I queue a number of cells in evaluation, and each is set to run something that will take a relatively long time to finish. I realize midway through the queue that one of the commands is erroneous, and I'd like to fix it without losing all of the calculations thus far. Is there a way to insert cells into (and remove cells from) the evaluation queue (perhaps from within a subsession) without aborting the entire evaluation?

Comment: Removing: use the token I used here: [**99582**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99582/5478) or select the cell Shift+Alt+.

Comment: Or select the cell bracket, left (Windows) or option (Max) click and choose "Remove from evaluation queue..."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Removing

Those three actions are using the same functionality, pick whatever is more convenient:

Assuming the desired cell is selected:

- menu item Evaluation / Remove from evaluation queue
- shortcut <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>
- token `FrontEndExecute @ FrontEndToken @ "RemoveFromEvaluationQueue"`

#### Inserting

I don't know if there is a general way because cells can be queued in a way independent from their vertical order in the notebook.

What comes to my mind is to remove all remaining cells, then add new and the rest again.